# Unable to publish my bot with bot framework for integrating with PVA getting error QNA Maker error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

i want to publish my microsoft bot framework in azure bot service and then need to integrate with power virtual agent by allowing and adding skill.

But when i publish bot for creating resource it give below error but bot service get created on azure service.
error file1

[image]

error:

> Provisioning completed 3 items before encountering a problem. {"name":"CREATE_QNA_ERROR","message":"Error - {"Code":"Unauthorized","Message":"This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU."},{"Code":"Unauthorized"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"52039","MessageTemplate":"{0}. Try selecting different region or SKU.","Parameters":["This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription"],"Code":"Unauthorized","Message":"This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU."}}],"Innererror":null}","stack":"Error\n at new CustomizeError (C:\Program Files\Bot Framework Composer\resources\app.asar.unpacked\extensions\azurePublish\dist\extension.js:276418:25)\n at createCustomizeError (C:\Program Files\Bot Framework Composer\resources\app.asar.unpacked\extensions\azurePublish\dist\extension.js:276423:10)\n at AzureResourceMananger.deployQnAReource (C:\Program Files\Bot Framework Composer\resources\app.asar.unpacked\extensions\azurePublish\dist\extension.js:277431:13)"}. See provision.occamsminebot.log in your bot folder.

when I am going to publish bot it gives error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create new Q&A Maker resource in Azure from 1st October 2022. Instead you should use Azure Cognitive Services for Language.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/whats-new#:~:text=The%20QnA%20Maker%20service%20is,Language%20Service%2C%20see%20question%20answering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/whats-new#:%7E:text=The%20QnA%20Maker%20service%20is,Language%20Service%2C%20see%20question%20answering).

Comment: Still no luck and my azure subscription has expired. I'll renewal the subscription and check. thanks @Aliaksandr Stadolnik .